# Setting mount options for PAM mounted ecryfptfs

Tags: mount, pam, ecryptfs

Is there any way of using (for example) the `lazytime` mount option with ecryptfs if it's automatically mounted by PAM when you login?

Comment: Does ecryptfs recognize & honor the mount options when mounting from a terminal, with `mount -t ecryptfs` or `mount.ecryptfs`?